# Less refer classes from different CSS files

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, class, nested, less

I'm creating a HTML/CSS page which is using Bootstrap. In fact I have to customize some parts. Because of several reasons some class names do not match the original from Bootstrap.
So, I have two files. bootstrap.min.css and main.less (=>main.min.css).
I'm wondering if it is possible to match classes in main.less to bootstrap.min.css.
So, I have a class .orderby (in main) which should have the same settings then .form-control (bootstrap).
Something like this:

```
.orderby { @.form-control }
```

But I have no clue how to refer to another css file.

Would appreciate if somebody can point me to the right feature.
Thank you!

Comment: Its better to refer the original bootstrap class name itself why create a new one unnecessarily which does the same thing! if you want to customize then copy the source code for that class from `bootstrap.css`, rename it and use it!

Comment: As I wrote, there are some reasons, I can't use the same class name. If I could use the same class names, I would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with LESS's [extend "all"](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-extend-all-). The generic form is `:extend(<indentifier> all) {}`. In your case, you'd do

```less
.orderby {
    &:extend(.form-control all) {}
    <your additional styles>
}
```

Additionally, if you don't need to use all of Bootstrap, you can import just the bits you need with LESS's [reference](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference):

```
@import (reference) path/to/bootstrap
```

Combine that with the above **extend** code, and you'll pull in just Bootstrap's `.form-control`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, @henry! this is what I need. I will look into it deeper and try to reach my goal using this function. Thanks again!

Comment: Great! If it ends up answering the question, go ahead and mark it closed by clicking the green check mark. And welcome to the world of asking things on SO!